# Selenium2 WebDriver (Page factory) error after a postback (Element not found in the cache)

Tags: postback, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2 tests (written in C#) that choose values from a "select" control. 
Selection causes a post-back to the server, which updates the state of the page.

It s really frustrating because every PostBack occurs this exception
**Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up**

Just to be precise i use Selenium 2 WebDriver (2.32.0.0)
And for my project i Use *Pattern Page Factory*

The code looks like that

```cs
class RegisterPersonelData
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl00_ContentMain_register1_txtName")]
    private IWebElement txtLastname;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl00_ContentMain_register1_lstDrvLic")]
    private IWebElement dlDrive;
    private SelectElement selectDrive;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl00_ContentMain_register1_lstVeh")]
    private IWebElement dlVehicule;
    private SelectElement selectVehicule;

    public RegisterPersonelData(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        // initialize elements of the LoginPage class
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
        // all elements in the 'WebElements' region are now alive!
        // FindElement or FindElements no longer required to locate elements
    }
    public void fillData(string lastname, string drive, string vehicule)
    {
        txtLastname.SendKeys(lastname);
        this.selectDrive = new SelectElement(dlDrive);
        selectDrive.SelectByText(drive);             

        selectVehicule = new SelectElement(dlVehicule);
        IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExpliciteWait"])));
        wait.Until(x => selectVehicule.Options.Count > 1);
        selectVehicule.SelectByText(vehicule);
    }
}
```

And here the code of main

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = MyWebDriver.GetWebDriver(MyWebDriver.BrowserType.FIFREFOX);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://...");
        ...
        registerPersonelData.fillData("lastname", "Permis B", "Auto");
     }
 }
```

This code doesn t work because one postback is triggered ... 
I have try to use one explicite wait but it fails too !
Code use to retrieve one element with explicite wait

```cs
public static IWait<IWebDriver> GetWaitWebDriver(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExpliciteWait"])));
        return wait;
    }

    public static IWebElement GetElementAndWaitForIt(IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        return GetWaitWebDriver(driver).Until(x => 
        {
            return x.FindElement(by);
        });
    }
```

Someone has one idea to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a lot of tries and finally i have found something usefull

```
public static void WaitForAnWebElementDisplayed(IWait<IWebDriver> wait, IWebElement webElement)
    {
        wait.Until(x => webElement.Displayed);
    }

    public static void WaitForAnWebElementEnabled(IWait<IWebDriver> wait, IWebElement webElement)
    {
        wait.Until(x => webElement.Enabled);
    }
```

and Consequently **i can wait that the load of page triggered after to have choosen one item in select option is completed** !

Answer (score 0):

You can re-initialize the elements at the end of the fillData method.

```
PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
```

You could do it in the main as well with:

```
PageFactory.InitElements(driver, registerPersonelData);
```

You could also try adding the following to the field you need to reuse.

```
[CacheLookup]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but ReInitialize elements don t help me because the key of my problem is I think to be able to wait with the correct conditions.

[CacheLookup] is a good idea to increase performance of my test :)